# Get Generic Type during runtime by name

Tags: powershell

I wonder why I can't retrieve a type with a generic definition, or more what can I do to achieve this.

My example:

```
[System.Collections.Generic.List`1].FullName

--> Outputs: System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

.

```
[System.Collections.Generic.List`1].AssemblyQualifiedName

--> Outputs: System.Collections.Generic.List`1, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

But both

```
[System.Type]::GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1")

[System.Type]::GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
```

Don't Output anything, even though the type of List is to be found in the mscorlib. Can somebody please explain me how I can find this type and other generic types by name?

Comment: [System.Collections.Generic.List`1].GetType()

Comment: Yea but for a certain reason, I have the type names as strings. :( So the only possible option would be to create the type and to keep the type definition saved in a variable? But honestly I don't believe there shouldn't be a way to find it out by the name at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `` ` `` is an escape character in PowerShell, you need to escape it in strings.
Either of these will work:

```
[System.Type]::GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List``1")
[System.Type]::GetType('System.Collections.Generic.List`1')
```